# How to fix PyFPDF encoding errors for different fonts?

Tags: python, encoding, fonts, pyfpdf

I have a font package that exists in the same folder as my code, and the following line is causing an error:

```
pdf.add_font('Garamond', '', 'Garamond Regular.ttf',)
```

It returns the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfa in position 16: invalid start byte
```

The program works if I use a standard font like Arial, but does not work if I use a different font like Garamond Regular.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.